# Powershell: convert a fraction to an integer - surprising rounding behavior

Tags: powershell, casting, integer, rounding, bankers-rounding

I have a interesting question on ints with decimals.

Assuming I do the following:

```
[int] $a = 5/2
$a
```

I've tried it 10 times to be sure, and powershell always returns `2`

Is there a way to force Powershell to round up or down in such circumstances and by default has it been set to round down?

I'm assuming depending on the machine and Powershell environment, I may get 3 at some points and 2 at others.

Comment: What you're seeing is often referred to as `integer math`. You're essentially forcing a casting of the result to an integer; which just drops anything after the decimal point. The result will be the same in any PS environment.

Comment: @gvee what you describe would be the `[Math]::Truncate` or the `[Math]::Floor` function. Powershell, however, uses the `[Math]::Round` function when casting a decimal to an int.

Comment: I used `[Math]::Floor` as an interchangeable for `[Math]Truncate` in my previous comment. That would only be true if you work with positive numbers. For negative numbers, `[Math]::Ceiling` would work the same way `[Math]::Truncate` does.

Comment: @J.Bergmann you are right! I did not know that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[Math]::Floor($a) --> 2
[Math]::Ceiling($a)--> 3
[Math]::Round($a) --> 2
```

`Floor` will give you the preceding whole number and `Ceiling` will be providing the succeeding whole number. 
But if you want to round it up, using the `Round` function, it will follow midpoint rounding (**Rounding at midpoint is historically away from zero**), as demonstrated below -

```
[Math]::Round(2.50) --> 2
[Math]::Round(2.51) --> 3
[Math]::Round(2.49) --> 2
[math]::Round(2.50,[System.MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero) --> 3
[math]::Round(2.49,[System.MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero) --> 2
[math]::Round(2.51,[System.MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero) --> 3
```

You can use either functions depending upon your requirement.

Comment: Rounding 2.5 to 2 isn't basic mathematics. This happens because Powershells default MidpointRounding mode is ToEven, so it will round ever .5 number to the nearest even integer. To use basic mathematics u can specify the MidpointRounding mode to AwayFromZero.

Comment: Is there a [Math]::Round() for 64 bit numbers in PowerShell 5.1 ?

Comment: @HenkPoley - Yes I believe there is. Refer to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-numbers-in-powershell/) blog. PowerShell supports 64-bit signed integer as long and an unsigned 64-bit integer as ulong.

Comment: Your answer would be much better if you'd variate the number before the `5` getting you to `1.5`, `2.5`, and `3.5` in the rounding examples. Also the bold "Rounding [...]" should be freed from the parentheses and break up the code box below into two parts. Hopefully you'll find the time to think about it.

Answer (score 9):

<sup>[Vivek Kumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48864546/45375) is helpful, but has some confusing aspects.</sup>

Generally, converting a fractional number to an integer invariably involves a form of *rounding*; in the context of *casting* and *implicit* conversion, programming languages typically use a form of **[rounding to the *nearest* integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_the_*nearest_integer*)**. **Special considerations** apply to the ambiguous case of **numbers whose fractional part is exactly `.5`**, for which **more than one strategy** exists - and different programming languages employ different strategies.

In the context of the **.NET Framework**, on which PowerShell is built, the **umbrella term** for these strategies is ***midpoint rounding***, and the specific strategy names used below refer to the midpoint (`.5`) as ***half*** for brevity (the examples below use PowerShell syntax, but apply to *all* .NET languages).

- ***Casting* to `[int]` *invariably*** employs **half-*to-even* rounding**, where numbers with a fractional part of `.5` are rounded to the nearest *even* integer (whether positive or negative):

  - `[int] 2.5` -> `2` (!) situational *down*-rounding, because the integer part happens to be *even* and positive
  - `[int] 3.5` -> `4` situational *up*-rounding
  - This rounding strategy also applies to *implicit* conversions to integer types that PowerShell sometimes performs - see last section.
  - PowerShell *syntax pitfall*: a cast has higher precedence than `/`, so `[int] 5/2` does *not* work as intended; use `[int] (5/2)`.
- To ***control* the midpoint rounding behavior**, use the **.NET [`[Math]` class'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=netstandard-2.0) [`Round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netstandard-2.0#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_MidpointRounding_) method**:

  - Use **`[int] [Math]::Round($number, [MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero)`** to get **half-*away-from-zero* rounding** (numbers with a fraction of `.5` are rounded to the nearest integer whose *absolute* value is *larger*).

    - `[Math]::Round(2.5, [MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero)` -> `3`
    - `[Math]::Round(-2.5, [MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero)` -> `-3`
    - Note: The `[Math]` methods (typically) return a `[double]`, so you may have to cast the result to `[int]` (or a different integer type) to get a true integer.

Note that `[Math]::Round()` offers not only to-*integer* rounding, but also to a specific number of *fractional digits*; e.g.,
`[Math]::Round(2.55, 1, [MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero)` yields `2.6`.<sup>Thanks, [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers).</sup>

---

**Other forms of rounding: Those where the specific value of the fractional part (other than `0`) is irrelevant:**

- Use **`[Math]::Truncate($number)`** to get ***toward-zero* rounding** (removal of the fractional part):

  - `[Math]::Truncate(2.1)` -> `2`; ditto for `2.5` and `2.9`, for instance
  - `[Math]::Truncate(-2.1)` -> `-2`
- Use **`[Math]::Ceiling($number)`** to get ***toward-positive-infinity* rounding** (rounding up to the nearest *greater-or-equal* integer):

  - `[Math]::Ceiling(2.1)` -> `3`
  - `[Math]::Ceiling(-2.1)` -> `-2` (!)
- Use **`[int] [Math]::Floor($number)`** to get ***toward-negative-infinity* rounding** (rounding down to the nearest *smaller-or-equal* integer):

  - `[Math]::Floor(2.1)` -> `2`
  - `[Math]::Floor(-2.1)` -> `-3` (!)

---

#### Optional further reading:

An example of PowerShell performing an *implicit* conversion in which this strategy is used:

`1..(2.5)` yields array `1, 2`, because the endpoint of the range-operator expression, `2.5`, was coerced to `[int]` `2`, so the expression is effectively the same as `1..2`

Since PowerShell is built on top of the .NET Framework, it is ultimately [`[Convert]::ToInt32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz(v=vs.110).aspx) that is called.

The intent behind the perhaps surprising *round-half-to-even* strategy is "to minimize the expected error when summing over rounded figures", [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

Wikipedia's page on rounding has a section on [rounding functions across programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_functions_in_programming_languages).

In contrast with .NET, *JavaScript*, for instance, employs *half-up* rounding (`Math.round(2.5)` -> `3`, `Math.round(-2.5)` -> `-2`) - a midpoint-rounding mode that .NET doesn't even offer.