# Powershell difference between 0.6 and 0.5 seconds feels weird

Tags: powershell

This isn not really a problem.  It might not be directly caused by powershell, but I have encountered this weird phenomenon today.  I even got bored and made a small script that clicks in a loop, so nothing serious.

Here is what is weird: 
When I added a small sleep into the loop to not have my system die due to gorrilions of clicks a second, I noticed a HUGE difference in frequency between:

`sleep 0.50001` - it was clearly visible that it was clicking twice a second.

and

`sleep 0.5` - was a LOT faster - it felt like at least 10 clicks a second.

I have tested this on the browser "game" cookie clicker to visualize this (okay, and to get rid of some boredom) and it got really obvious there.

To the question: Can anyone explain to me why `0.5` is apparently a lot faster than `0.50001` in powershell?

PS: I have tested it with `0.4`, `0.6` too - its as if 0.5 is the border between normal and subsonic speed.

Comment: Seconds take an `[int]` and .NET rounds to nearest even integer by default :-) Use the `-Milliseconds` parameter explicitly and specify 400, 500 or 600 instead

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864295/powershell-int-variable-with-decimal-number/48864546#48864546) answer by mklement0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You're the victim of midpoint rounding!

Let's have a look at the syntax for `Start-Sleep`:

```
PS C:\> Get-Command Start-Sleep -Syntax

Start-Sleep [-Seconds] <int> [<CommonParameters>]

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds <int> [<CommonParameters>]
```

As you can see, the default parameter set takes the `Seconds` to sleep as an integer.

When you supply a `Double`, PowerShell tries to convert your input value to an integer, and `0.5` and below gets rounded to `0`, thanks to the [default midpoint rounding mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx#Midpoint) employed by .NET

So `[int]0.50001` is equal to `1` and `[int]0.5` is equal to `0`

Comment: that cool, thanks - i completely forgot what an integer is at that point, guess i should repeat 6th grade

Answer (score 0):

The issue is rounding as Jessen said.

There is one thing:

`Sleep` is not a PowerShell function it is a **batch** file's one (as Jessen correctly said it is also a PowerShell an *alias* to `Start-Sleep` do not confuse them.).  Not to confuse them Microsoft probably decided to use `Start-Sleep` for PowerShell instead of simple `Sleep` and added alias for that.

If you want to do it the *PowerShell* way use `Start-Sleep`.  You won't get confused if you add the `-Milliseconds` there:

```
Start-Sleep [-Seconds] <int>  [<CommonParameters>]
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds <int>  [<CommonParameters>]
```

To check that it is "only" alias

```
PS U:\> get-alias -name sleep

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Alias           sleep -> Start-Sleep
```

Comment: `sleep` is an alias for `Start-Sleep`.

Comment: @Joey Yes, that is true.  You have to just watch out if you are in the mixed environment using batch and powershell not to mix them.  That is why I prefer `Start-Sleep` over the alias `Sleep`.  And that is why I have written that Sleep is a batch file function.

Comment: It's still wrong. `sleep` is not a native command present on normal Windows installations. Within PowerShell it's the alias and thus equivalent to `Start-Sleep`.

Comment: @Joey It is native command within batch file not a command.  It will work everywhere.  You can create a `test.bat`  and put there `SLEEP 10` it will work there - normal Windows installation.

Comment: Normal Windows installation here: `'sleep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` It has been part of some Windows Resource Kits in the past. Maybe you have one of them installed. Or GnuWin32 or similar. But the built-in way of waiting on Windows would be either `timeout` or `ping`, but not `sleep`.

Comment: @Joey that all depends on your definition of "normal" - if you mean by out-of-the box then no. e.g. I'm using windows 2003 with Windows resource Kit. Running it produces `sleep /? Usage: sleep time-to-sleep-in-seconds sleep [-m] time-to-sleep-in-milliseconds sleep [-c] commited-memory ratio (1%-100%)`