# Powershell Round Up Function

Tags: powershell, math, rounding

I would like to round up to two decimal places in Powershell.

I start with the double "178.532033". If I use the Excel ROUNDUP function to two decimal places I get "178.54".

```
=ROUNDUP(A1,2)
```

However, if I use the Round function contained within the Math class in Powershell I get the result "178.53" (because I am rounding as opposed to rounding up):

```
$value = 178.532033

Write-Output = ([Math]::Round($value, 2))
```

Is there a way to round up to two decimal places in Powershell?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864295/powershell-int-variable-with-decimal-number)?
See [the detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864295/powershell-int-variable-with-decimal-number/48893799#48893799) by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0).

Comment: `[Math]::Round([Math]::Ceiling($value * 100) / 100, 2)`

Comment: [Math]::Ceiling($value * 100) / 100;

Comment: @KirillPashkov The division returns a double value. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for why rounding that result is not optional.

Comment: A rational round up function would give 178.53 if I understand it correctly.  You'd get 178.54 if the thousandths value was 5-9.

Comment: @duffymo That would be normal rounding behavior. The OP wants to replicate the behavior of the Excel [`ROUNDUP()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUNDUP-function-F8BC9B23-E795-47DB-8703-DB171D0C42A7) function, which always rounds UP (hence the name).

Answer (score 20):

This is handled easily by the `ceiling` and `floor` methods of the math class.

Script:

```
$a = 657
$b = 234

$a/$b
[math]::floor($a/$b)
[math]::ceiling($a/$b)
```

Output:

```
2.80769230769231
2
3
```

If you want to round to two decimal places, multiply by 100 before using floor/ceiling then divide the result by 100.

I find that you are rarely going to be the last person to edit a PowerShell script, and keeping them simple is key to not getting an e-mail a year later wondering what you were doing with a complex transformation in a script that no longer works.

Answer (score 7):

Just add 0.005 before rounding:

```
$value = 178.532033
Write-Output = ([Math]::Round($value + 0.005, 2))
```

This takes the interval [1.000, 1.010) to [1.005, 1.015). All the values in the first interval ROUNDUP(2) to 1.01, and all the values in the second interval ROUND(2) to 1.01.

In general, if rounding to k places after the decimal, add 0.5/10^k to round up, or subtract that to round down, by rounding the result normally.

Comment: Simple, effective, beautiful. Great answer.

Comment: Goes the wrong way for negative values

Answer (score 1):

Rounddown:

```
$a = 9;
$b = 5;
[math]::truncate($a/$b)
```

Roundup:

```
$a = 9;
$b = 5;
if ( ($a % $b) -eq 0 )
{
  $a/$b
}
else 
{
  [math]::truncate($a/$b)+1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want the returned value padded with zeros.

Given the value `10.99822`

```
[Math]::Ceiling(10.99822 * 100)/100
```

Returns: `11`

To add zero padding:

```
"{0:n2}" -f ([Math]::Ceiling(10.99822 * 100)/100)
```

Returns: `11.00`