# Powershell: how to intialize an array of bytes like in C?

Tags: arrays, powershell, byte, list-initialization

In C you can do something like:

```
uint16_t datalen = 1024;
uint16_t crc = 0x1021;
uint8_t myHeader = {0x41, 0xBE, 0x21, 0x08, datlen/256, datalen%256, crc/256, crc%256};
```

Now, how can I accomplish an array initialization like this in Powershell?

I want to send the byte array later to serial port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so different:

```
[uint16]$datalen = 1024
[uint16]$crc = 0x1021
[byte[]]$myHeader = 0x41, 0xBE, 0x21, 0x08, ($datalen/256), ($datalen%256), ($crc/256), ($crc%256)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I missed the variable casting to [uint16] before the byte array.

Comment: Hm, I was to early to take it as good, the problem is with the division, it is performed by rounding up the result, which is not wanted. How to avoid that?

Comment: I think I have to use [Math]::Floor(), rigth? It is a bit of pain because it reduces readability, but at least it works.

Comment: See [round fraction to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48893799/1701026)