# How can I define rounded variable in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing short powershell to fill contract in htm file. I have a problem in definig rounded up variables $FirstFee and $SecondFee.

The script is :

```
$InvoiceValue = Read-Host -Prompt 'Write invoice value'
$FirstFee = [int]$InvoiceValue*0.023+40
$SecondFee = [int]$InvoiceValue*0.023+60
```

The result is presented i.ex 1234*0.23+40=323,82 instead od 324.

Where do I make a mistake?

I the next step I replace the result of rounded $FirstFee and $SecondFee in a RTF file, but the values must be rounded.

Comment: `$roundedFirstFee = [math]::round($FirstFee)`

Comment: You could also just change `$FirstFee = ...` to `[int]$FirstFee = ...`

Comment: Thank you for this comment. This way I'm defining two variables. I would like to create one.

Comment: `$FirstFee = [math]::Round([int]$InvoiceValue * 0.23 + 40)`

Comment: `$FirstFee = [int]($InvoiceValue*0.023+40)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

You need *two* casts, one for `$InvoiceValue`, and another for the *result* of the calculation.

```sh
$FirstFee = [int] ([int] $InvoiceValue * 0.023 + 40)
```

Alternatively, *type-constrain* the receiving variable (place the cast to the *left* of the variable name in the assignment), which has the same effect (while also coercing any values assigned in the future to `[int]`:

```sh
[int] $FirstFee = [int] $InvoiceValue * 0.023 + 40
```

Note that an `[int]` cast performs *half-to-even* rounding, so that *both* `[int] 1.5` and `[int] 2.5` return `2`. To control the rounding behavior, use [`[Math]::Round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Math.Round) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48893799/45375).

---

**Background information**:

- PowerShell casts - such as `[int]` - have high [precedence in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence), so that `[int] $InvoiceValue * 0.023 + 40` is the same as: `([int] $InvoiceValue) * 0.023 + 40`
- PowerShell performs many automatic type conversions; **in a numeric context, mismatched operand types cause the other operand to be automatically promoted to the larger among the operand types** - and if the *result* doesn't fit into that type, PowerShell automatically switches to `[double]`<sup>[1]</sup>.

In the following example, the result is of type `[double]` because `[double]` is larger than `[int]`.

```sh
# Note: The [int] cast isn't strictly necessary here.
#       PowerShell defaults to [int] for integer number literals, if small enough.
([int] 1 * 0.5).GetType().Name # -> Double
```

Therefore, in order to force the *result* to be an `[int]` again, another `[int]` cast is needed around the *entire calculation*.

---

<sup>[1] This behavior is somewhat unfortunate, because for *integer* types it would be preferable to switch to a large *integer* type (e.g., `[long]`) rather than `[double]`, because using `[double]` for very large integers results in loss of accuracy. It is only in PowerShell *number literals*, that the preferable behavior is applied; e.g.: `(2147483648).GetType().Name` indicates `[long]` - PowerShell automatically chose `[long]`, because the number can no longer fit in an `[int]` (its value is `[int]::MaxValue + 1`); by contrast, arriving at the equivalent number *by calculation* results in the undesirable to-`[double]` promotion: `([int]::MaxValue + 1).GetType().Name` reports `[double]`.</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer solves myproblem in 100%.