# Integer division in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, integer-division

What is the easiest way to do integer division in PowerShell? So that the arguments are integers and the result is also an integer.

In C++ it would be e.g. `115/10`.

Comment: the result of `115/10` would be a `double` in powershell so now you need to tell us which type of rounding do you prefer to convert that double into an integer. It might be as easy as `115 / 10 -as [int]` or you might need to use `[Math]::Round` with the `MidpointRounding` overload.

Comment: Read up on [About_Arthmetic_operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-7.3).  It will show you how to get rounding behavior that's diffferent from the powershell default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For true integer division, use [`System.Math.Truncate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Math.Truncate) and cast the result to `[int]`:

```bash
[int] [Math]::Truncate(115 / 10) # -> 11
```

Alternatively, use [`System.Math.DivRem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Math.DivRem), which directly returns an `[int]` (or `[long]`):

```bash
[Math]::DivRem(115, 10, [ref] $null) # -> 11
```

In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), additional, integer-type specific overloads are available that return *tuples*, so you may alternatively use:

```bash
# PowerShell 7+ only.
[Math]::DivRem(115, 10)[0] # -> 11
```

---

PowerShell widens numerical types on demand, and switches to `[double]` for division with integer operands (of any integer type, such as `[int]`) that would yield a remainder.

Casting to the result of a division to `[int]` (e.g. `[int] (115 / 10)`) is *not* the same as using `[Math]::Truncate()`, as that performs half-to-even *rounding* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48893799/45375) for details.